# On youtube is it possible to block certain types of videos while in playback mode?

Tags: youtube, video-playback

Say I had searched for a song from artist A and then let it play in the background. Youtube will pick for me the next video to play. Sometimes the pick is good and sometimes less good. I was wondering if there would be a way  to customize my experience and say - while in playback mode - I do not want to be suggested with videos containing the word: "C" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

The best Youtube offiers, is the following...

While you watch a video, you can add videos to a playlist, including the watch later playlist.

You can then start watching videos from your watch playlist.